# Refresh token method in Sony's Lifelog API returning 500 error

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

I'm trying to use the refresh_token for sony's lifelog api but it's returning 500 error. I'm sending the request to https://platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com/oauth/2/refresh_token

My request is:

```
POST /oauth/2/refresh_token HTTP/1.1
Host: platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

refresh_token=[MY_REFRESH_TOKEN]&grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=[MY_CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[MY_CLIENT_SECRET]
```

The response is:

```
{
"fault": {
    "faultstring": "Execution of ServiceCallout CheckRefreshTokenStatus failed. Reason: ResponseCode 500 is treated as error",
    "detail": {
        "errorcode": "steps.servicecallout.ExecutionFailed"
        }
    }
}
```

I have no issues with authenticating or using the API otherwise, it's just this call that's giving me errors.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I just checked the API and the call to the refresh token seems to still be working for me. Is there any chance you have reached your limit of 25,000 call per day as defined here: https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/create-app/increase-rate-limit/. If so you can send a request to the contact listed on that page to try and have your limit increased.

Comment: I'm still having this issue. I also tried adding Accept: application/json and Accept-Encoding: gzip to my header but it didn't work. If it matters at all I'm asking for activity and profile permissions and not location permission from lifelog. There isn't a chance that I'm reaching my limit, I'm just testing this service out and I'm the only one using my app. One thing to note: if I change my refresh token to something invalid I get an "Invalid token" response so it seems that the service recognises my token as correct but fails in handling it.

Comment: @Robert-Sony So I created a sony entertainment account and using that account the refresh token worked. When logged in with my google+ account it did not work. I'm guessing that you would like to fix that on your end.

Comment: ok that makes sense. There is an issue with the Google account sign in that the team is working on.